# ios frosted glass logic

Tags: ios, background, uibutton

**Frosted Glass Effect**

I'm thinking of how to approach this logically..

So we take the background image ( for example )

[image]

Then, we want to add our frosted glass button to this image. Here's how it should look..

[image]

Now I know I cannot programatically blur the background image of the button, so I'll to try and do it with two images.. Background.png and Backgorund_Blurred.png.

Now, the frosted glass effect will happen on animated objects. So, as they move across the screen, it should appear that it is blurring the background image behind it, however, to achieve this I can only think of one way. But doing so is beyond my current capability.

It would have to be a background_blurred image for the UIButton for example. No scaled in any way, and the exact same size as the normal background. Then, I would have to take the buttons relative position on the normal background and append the background_blurred of the button to suit.

***My first question; is this possible?***

***Second question; is there an easier approach?***

Lastly, I've added an image to make sense of the relative position theory.

[image]

Comment: Check out the FXBlur library, it'll let you blur images/views.. I've used it successfully and sounds like it'll do what you want.

Comment: @Jay thanks man, so is it not taking the approach I was thinking?

Comment: No, I think having two images for these assets maybe easier, but having the views blur may be better in the long run as you wouldn't have to worry about updating the images for different resolutions in the future or care about how big the button is/will be.. Also if you want to do this with more images it'll turn into a mess with all the different images to manage.. The library is simple to use, with one call you'll have a blurred image/view..

Comment: @Jay Thanks again, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the FXBlur library, it'll let you blur images/views.. I've used it successfully and sounds like it'll do what you want.

I think having two images for these assets maybe easier, but having the views blur may be better in the long run as you wouldn't have to worry about updating the images for different resolutions in the future or care about how big the button is/will be.. Also if you want to do this with more images it'll turn into a mess with all the different images to manage.. The library is simple to use, with one call you'll have a blurred image/view..